# JSF 2 Mojarra -- Can I configure the app to always use numbered XML entities instead of named entities?

Tags: xml, jsf, entities, mojarra

I'm noticing that mojarra outputs named html entities in many cases as opposed to numbered entities. This seems to cause issues when using an application/xhtml+xml content type. I looked through some mojarra configuration options but wasn't able to find a way to configure the application to always use numbered entities. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard renderkit of JSF is designed to output (X)HTML, not XML. You need to supply a 3rd party renderkit or to create a custom renderkit which outputs XML. No 3rd party ones comes to mind however.

Apart from that, if you intend to return XML upon a web request, then JSF is not really the right tool for the job. Better head to [JAX-WS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html) or [JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html).

By the way, the right XML content type is not `application+xml` but `application/xml`.

Comment: This is for a mobile web application which JSF works great for -- except for a couple of minor doctype issues when using a mobile doctype. HTML entities really would work fine as well if I can just figure out how to retain entity defintions in the doctype definition (I've posted this question as well). I'll pursue that avenue. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Oh, that changes a lot. Can you please point out which components are rendering named HTML entities instead of numbered XML entities?

Comment: Here are a couple of examples: <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> <!ENTITY pound "&#163;">

Comment: Hm, I am confused. You was talking about JSF components which are rendering named HTML entities. I understood that you're talking about for example `<h:outputText>` --> `javax.faces.component.UIOutput`. That are JSF components.

Comment: Sorry, no. The use case would be including them directly in a facelet, as in: <h1>&#163;10</h1>. When they are parsed and output they render as <h1>&pound;10</h1>

Comment: Oh, this way. Hmm, I cannot reproduce this on Mojarra 2.0.4 with Facelets. It just renders as `<h1>£10</h1>` (yes, the entity is already processed).

Comment: you would have to set com.sun.faces.disableUnicodeEscaping to false to see it.

Comment: Yes, reproduced. Before diving into this, can you elaborate why it is for you necessary to set it to false?

Comment: Great question. QA was finding some browsers (mac safari??) that were displaying whacky characters when it was set to auto in mojarra 2.0.4. I haven't retested this in 2.1.1 yet.

Comment: Hm, is the response content type charset set to UTF-8? Facelets should already to that by default however. Explore the response headers using some HTTP debugging tool like Firebug.